# What is the clear button on html5smartimage

Tags: image, aem

I have inherited a scaffold form that contains an html5smartimage component. This is used to allow a user to select a display image for this page.

(I know this is not what this component is designed for, but I don't know what features the users are using and we are specifying a height.)

Here is the config info:

```
    <featuredImage
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        allowUpload="false"
        ddGroups="[media]"
        disableZoom="{Boolean}true"
        fileNameParameter="./jcr:content/data/image/fileName"
        fileReferenceParameter="./jcr:content/data/image/fileReference"
        name="./jcr:content/data/image"
        title="Featured Image"
        height="400"
        xtype="html5smartimage"/>
```

When an image is added, there is a clear button with a picture of a brush to sweep something away. I assume it is there to clear the image, but it is always disabled.

I cannot find this clear button referenced in any documentation.

Based on the answer below, I built the following that solves my problem:

```
    <featuredImage
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        allowUpload="false"
        ddGroups="[media]"
        disableZoom="{Boolean}true"
        fileNameParameter="./jcr:content/data/image/fileName"
        fileReferenceParameter="./jcr:content/data/image/fileReference"
        name="./jcr:content/data/image"
        title="Featured Image"
        height="400"
        xtype="html5smartimage">
      <listeners
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        imagestate="function(imageComponent, state) {
                      if(state == 'originalavailable' || state == 'processedavailable') {
                          imageComponent.enableToolbar();
                      }
                    }"/>
    </featuredImage>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across a similar kind of issue when using a custom widget and not scaffold form. However the fix should work for this too.

Add a listener to your image as shown below

```
listeners: {
    imagestate: function(imageComponent, state) {
        if(state == 'originalavailable' || state == 'processedavailable') {
            imageComponent.enableToolbar();
        }
    }
}
```

This would enable the clear button when you drop the image in the dialog.

Comment: I have edited my question with the code as I think it should be added, but no dice. When you say "add to your image" add how?